# root.overrideredirect() removes tkinter app from taskbar

Tags: python, tkinter, window-managers

I have a clock app which when I make it fullscreen disappears from the taskbar and also makes the app inaccessible through Alt+Tab. It's apparently caused by `root.overrideredirect(True)` function which I use to fullscreen the app. Is there a way I can fullscreen the `tkinter` and keep in on the taskbar?

This is the code for fullscreen:

```py
def toggleFullScreen(event):
    if fullScreen:
        deactivateFullscreen()
    else:
        activateFullscreen()

def activateFullscreen():
    global fullScreen, geometry
    fullScreen = True
    geometry = root.geometry()      # Store geometry for reset
    root.overrideredirect(True)     # Hides borders and make truly fullscreen
    root.state("zoomed")            # Maximize window, optionally set screen

def deactivateFullscreen():
    global fullScreen, geometry
    fullScreen = False
    root.state("normal")
    root.geometry(geometry)
    root.overrideredirect(False)
```

Comment: It's how `Tk.overrideredirect` works. What OS are you using? If it's Windows, you can use something like `ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowLongPtrW` and `ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowLongPtrW` instead of the `overrideredirect`. For an example look at [this](https://github.com/TheLizzard/BetterTk/blob/42320b3f3a0e36596accc12ab0767506e050024f/src/bettertk/notitlebartk_win.py#L122C41-L122C41)

Comment: The app you linked doesn't work for second screen. When I click "fullscreen" on second screen, the app goes fullscreen on primary screen.

Comment: In the code that I linked, there is a `fullscreen` method. It uses `tkinter`'s `attributes("-fullscreen", True)`. If you are using that and it doesn't work, try using `state("zommed")` instead. I don't have a second monitor to test it so I can't help a lot.