# Remove titlebar without using overrideredirect() using Tkinter on Windows

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, titlebar, customtkinter

Is it possible to remove the titlebar from a tkinter application without effecting other parts of the application like `overrideredirect()`?

I am currently using python (3.10). On top of that I am using `customtkinter` but as `customtkinter` is build on top of tkinter any why to achieve my desired application should work with `customtkinter`.

If there is a solution that involves just `customtkinter` or any other library/package I will take that solution too.

*Note - I found solutions that do work for linux and other OS but none that currently work for Windows. Please Help, if it's even possible.

I have already tried `app.attributes("-fullscreen", True)` and `.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')` solutions that were recommended by other users on posts, but they did not work.

Comment: Look at `customtkinter`'s docs for a solution. If there is none, look at the comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77655106/11106801) `tkinter` question. Basically you would have to use Windows' API.